# Get Appropriate CGRect for an NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring, cgrect, nstextattachment

As it is clear from the title I'm trying to find the appropriate size for bounds of a `UILabel` containing an `NSAttributedString` which contains some images using `NSTextAttachment`.

Before using the `attributedText` property of the `UILabel`, I was using `text` property which carries the plain text only, and the method I was using was

`sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(220, 9999) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping`

And it was working fine. But now I have changed the type of contents in my `UILabel` and this method no longer gives the correct size ( Because it does not consider width of images ).

I have Googled a lot and the only thing I did end up with for `NSAttributedString` was

`boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(220.f, CGFLOAT_MAX)
  options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
  context:nil`

But it is not returning the appropriate size and most of the content is lost in UI using this method. So please either suggest another solution or if you are suggesting `boundingRectWithSize` please come up with clear instruction on how can I make it work.

Just in case it helps, What I'm trying to show is a text message that may contain smilies (Custom Images, not Emojis of course) and those smilies are stored and shown as `NSTextAttachment`s.

Comment: No, I haven't tested without emoticons first. The reason I said I know that the problem is about images is that I see the way it reacts to the text when I mix smilies and texts in different types. Since I don't have access to code right now, I have put that testing ( without emoticons ) in a priority to-do list to do as the first thing in the morning ( It's midnight in my time-zone ), But the behavior I saw from the function has convinced me that it's the images that are causing problem.
BTW, None of my words were offensive bro, thanks for your attention and comments :)

Comment: Everything is Ok for me. I read what I've written again and for sure it's badly turned and you can feel I'm exhausted or offended. That's why I remove the comments as for now they don't help you and they do not appear the way i want.